# ¿Hay forma de dejar bloqueado un botón o forma en excel para que no se mueva?

Tags: excel, vba

Estoy intentando colocar un botón o una forma con propiedades de botón en una hoja de excel, y lo que pretendo es que no se mueva al hacer scroll (horizontal o vertical), es decir, que no quede anclado a ninguna celda, y siempre permanezca visible dentro de la hoja activa. ¿Es posible?

Comment: Lo único que se me ocurre es que inmovilices paneles dejando dentro del rango la forma que quieres fija. O moverla con VBA permanentemente, pero eso sobrecarga todo. Veo más fácil bloquear las dos o 3 primeras filas de la hoja y dejar ahí la forma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma de hacerlo bastante limpia ha sido colocar los botones en un form de VBA, al que hemos establecido su propiedad 'modal' a 'false', para que se pueda seguir trabajando en el documento sin problemas.
Haciendo unas llamadas a la API de Windows, conseguimos que el form no tenga la barra de título y de esta forma solo se ve un marco alrededor de los botones, y además el form no se puede cerrar mientras el libro está abierto, lo cual soluciona el problema de un cierre accidental.

El código es este:

```
Const GWL_STYLE = -16
Const WS_CAPTION = &HC00000
Private Declare Function GetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long, ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function DrawMenuBar Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function FindWindowA Lib "user32" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim lngWindow As Long, lFrmHdl As Long
    lFrmHdl = FindWindowA(vbNullString, Me.Caption)
    lngWindow = GetWindowLong(lFrmHdl, GWL_STYLE)
    lngWindow = lngWindow And (Not WS_CAPTION)
    Call SetWindowLong(lFrmHdl, GWL_STYLE, lngWindow)
    Call DrawMenuBar(lFrmHdl)
End Sub
```

Por último, hay que incluir algunas líneas más de código en las hojas del libro que queremos mostrar los botones, con la instrucción '.show' del form establecida a 'true' o 'false', según nuestras necesidades.

De este modo, podemos hacer scroll horizontal o vertical, o desplazarnos con el teclado por la hoja, y los botones siempre estarán ahí.
El resultado visual es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: recorda aceptar esta respuesta!

Answer (score 1):

Para bloquear un botón puedes utilizar esto:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    On Error GoTo 0
    With Cells(Windows(1).ScrollRow, Windows(1).ScrollColumn)
        CommandButton1.Top = .Top + 100
        CommandButton1.Left = .Left + 300
    End With
End Sub
```

Ojo tiene que ser un boton ActiveX.

Para una forma prueba con algo así:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    With ActiveSheet.Shapes(1)

        .Left = ActiveWindow.VisibleRange(5, 5).Left
        .Top = ActiveWindow.VisibleRange(5, 5).Top

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Gracias! El comportamiento no es exactamente el esperado, ya que no funciona al hacer scroll con el ratón, pero sí si movemos la celda activa con las flechas del teclado. Supongo que habrá que buscar otro evento que dispare la Sub, y me has dado una idea de por donde trabajar. Saludos!